# How to use a variable as the amount for recurring payments (Paypal API)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using the Paypal API to create a subscription system where there are two types of subscriptions
Monthly subscription (5dlls)
Annual subscription  (50dlls)
I currently  have the following code:

For setting the checkout:

```
public function do_purchase($type){     

    $this->load->library('paypal');

    $requestParams = array(
       'RETURNURL' => site_url('restaurant/get_purchase_details'),
       'CANCELURL' => site_url('restaurant/afiliaturestaurante')
    );

    $orderParams = array(
       'L_BILLINGTYPE0' => 'RecurringPayments',
       'L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0' => 'Monthly',
       'AMT' => 0 
    );


    $paypal = new Paypal();
    $response = $paypal -> request('SetExpressCheckout',$requestParams + $orderParams);


    if(is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { //Request successful
        $token = $response['TOKEN'];
        header( 'Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token) );
    }


}
```

For creating the recurring Paypal profile:

```
public function get_purchase_details(){

    if( isset($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['token']) ) { // Token parameter exists
       // Get checkout details, including buyer information.
       // We can save it for future reference or cross-check with the data we have

       $this->load->library('paypal');

       $paypal = new Paypal();
       $checkoutDetails = $paypal -> request('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', array('TOKEN' => $_GET['token']));

       // Complete the checkout transaction
       $requestParams = array(
            'TOKEN' => $_GET['token'],
            'PAYERID' => $checkoutDetails['PAYERID'],
            'PROFILESTARTDATE' => '2014-03-7T05:38:48Z',
            'DESC' => 'Monthly',
            'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
            'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '1',
            'AMT' => '5',
            'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
            'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
            'MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS' => '3',
       );

       $response = $paypal -> request('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile',$requestParams);


       if( is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { // Payment successful
           // We'll fetch the transaction ID for internal bookkeeping
           $profileID = $response['PROFILEID'];


       }
    }
}
```

I need to use $type variable on get_purchase_details for setting the amount of the profile, how can I pass the variable through Paypal so I can user on the other function? I'm using a Paypal library for creating the cURL requests.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just set the value of $type in a session variable, and that would be available upon return from PayPal.

Alternatively, you could pass your $type value in the CUSTOM parameter of SetExpressCheckout and that way it'll be returned in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer again. I ended up passing the value through the URL in RETURNURL

    'RETURNURL' => site_url('restaurant/get_purchase_details/' . $type);

Thanks for all your help!